# Nvidia 9800 GT detects DVI monitor as VGA

Tags: graphics-card, dvi

I have an Nvidia 9800 GT 512 MB. The card seems to have a faulty VGA output, or the monitor has a faulty VGA input. That's not the problem - the problem is that I need to use DVI on this monitor because of this VGA issue. It supports it - it has a DVI single link connector with all the digital pins but crucially it also has the analog pins, and seems to communicate itself as an analog monitor. The monitor can be switched to digital video, but when I do that, it switches back, because there is no digital signal. How do I set it to go to digital mode only?

Here's the odd thing: It POSTs in digital mode. I can see that on the OSD. But Windows and Ubuntu both switch into analog mode.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This one may be obvious, but did you try setting the monitor to digital and then connecting it to the card?

Comment: @AndrejaKo, I would do so. But I can't, as the OSD is unusable with no video input. :(

Comment: So we have great product design at work right here! Unfortunately, I have nothing useful to say.

Answer (score 0):

Get a DVI-D cable. These do not have those VGA pins. You can tell them apart: They are the 4 pins around the long one. They are simply missing on DVI-D cables.

### DVI-I

```
   \   \    \\\\\
   -----    \\\\\
   \   \    \\\\\
```

### DVI-D

```
            \\\\\
   -----    \\\\\
            \\\\\
```

Comment: You can't always tell them apart, a cable may be using the DVI-I connector but missing the wires corresponding to the analog pins; it would then be a DVI-D cable, but you'd need an ohmmeter to tell.